# How to update template on Django view request post

Tags: django

I am doing some filtering. I have initial results on my page, then there is a form, that on select, I want to filter some data and update template.

The template doesn't seem to be updated though.

```
from .services import service
# Home Page View
def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    update_list = service.get_updates()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        filter_string = request.POST.get('filter')
        update_list = [update for update in update_list if update['type'] == filter_string]

    print(len(update_list))

    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(update_list, 2)

    try:
        updates = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        updates = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        updates = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    context = {
        'updates': updates
    }

    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

Template file:

```
<form method="post" id="filterformhome">
     {% csrf_token %}
<select class="frm-input" onchange="homeFilter(this);">
<option value="job">{% trans "Jobs" %}</option>
<option value="market">{% trans "Products" %}</option>
<option value="question">{% trans "Questions" %}</option>
<option value="blog">{% trans "Blogs" %}</option>
</select>
</form>

{% for update in updates %}
  {{update.title}}
{% endfor %}
```

What would be the better way of doing this?

Comment: Can you share your "home.html" file as well?

Comment: template code has been added

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JS for that, otherwise you will only see the change reflected by refreshing the page.